# Как считывать определённый диапазон байтов из файла?

Tags: python, файлы, распараллеливание

Мне необходимо на питоне считывать из файла x байтов, начиная с n-го байта.
Я пользуюсь обычным seek(n), а затем read(x), но возникает проблема.

Программа работает паралельно и считывает множество записей из разных мест разных файлов. Что бы файлы не открывать много раз вновь, их файловые переменные кэшируются. Из-за этого разные потоки могут управлять одной и той же файловой переменной. И бывает так, что в одном потоке указатель перемещается на позицию x, затем другой поток двигает этот указатель ещё раз на нужную ему позицию x1 и только потом первый поток считывает свои n байтов и естественно получает неверные значения.

Я пробовал решить это изменив функцию кэширования, теперь кэшируется не одна файловая переменная, а сразу несколько и функция следит, что бы с каждой переменной в одно время взаимодействоал только один поток. Однако, возникла новая проблема, связанная с ошибкой OSError: [Errno 24] Too many open files: 'file.txt'. В windows нельзя открыть больше 8192 файлов одновременно, а мне нужно больше. И я не смог имзенить этот лимит ни в рестре, ни сторонними программами.

Ищу ответ у более умных людей, каким образом можно решить данную проблему. Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Попробовать mmap?

Comment: andreymal, та же проблема. Открытие файла в mmap тратит лимиты числа открылых файлов в OS. И точно так же одну и ту же файловую переменную нельзя использовать в нескольких потоках одновременно, так как пермещение по ней и считывание происходят независимо.

Comment: Чувствую, что нужно зайти с другой стороны — зачем вам это всё нужно-то вообще? Что такое страшное вы делаете, что упираетесь в лимиты?

Comment: Всего лишь собственную СУБД для поиска по таблицам на 5-10 терабайт. Пока скорость поиска около 500 запросов в секунду и дальнейшая оптимизация упирается как раз в такие проблемы.